# Function and Code

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to have an answer which has some code outside of a function? For example, in Python, if you were to get the sum of two square roots, would this be allowed:

```
import math
R=math.sqrt
def f(x,y):
 return R(x)+R(y)
```

or would it have to be this:

```
def f(x,y):
 import math
 R=math.sqrt
 return R(x)+R(y)
```

or maybe this:

```
import math
def f(x,y):
 R=math.sqrt
 return R(x)+R(y)
```